# NodeMCU does not connect to wifi

Tags: esp8266, nodemcu

I'm trying to connect my nodeMCU to my WiFi network but it keeps printing **`........`** which means is not connecting to the network. Here is my code used to connect to WiFi. Any reason why it isn't connecting to WiFi network?.

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>

        // Replace these with your WiFi network settings
        const char* ssid = "******"; //replace this with your WiFi network name
        const char* password = "******"; //replace this with your WiFi network password

        void setup()
        {
          delay(1000);
          Serial.begin(57600);

          WiFi.begin(ssid, password);

          Serial.println();
          Serial.print("Connecting");
          while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED)
          {
            delay(500);
            Serial.print(".");
          }

          Serial.println("success!");
          Serial.print("IP Address is: ");
          Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
        }

        void loop() {
        }
```

Comment: could  be that your router is refusing the connection

Comment: @jsotola how to fix it?

Comment: that is only a guess ..... there could be other reasons ...... try connecting to another network ..... maybe one that does not require a password

Comment: try WiFiScan example

Comment: @Juraj I tried it and it shows all the WiFi connection available.

Comment: including the SSID you want to connect?

Comment: @Juraj Yes including the one im trying to connect

Comment: has the ssid or password unusual characters like space, hashtag, dolar?

Comment: @Juraj No only letters and numbers. Btw what if remove the password? can i pass an empty string to the password variable?

Comment: use only one parameter, the ssid

Comment: has the network, you want to connect, DHCP?

Comment: @Juraj No its not DHCP

Comment: then assign IP address

Comment: @Juraj How to do that?

Comment: try to print `WiFi.status()` instead of '.'. or better `wifi_station_get_connect_status()`

Comment: did you solve it?

Comment: I also have the same issue but i can connect it with mobile hotspot!! so just try in this method

Comment: 5ghz networks will not connect to esp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your WiFi network doesn't have DHCP, then you must set the IP addresses

example:

```
  IPAddress ip(192, 168, 1, 8);
  IPAddress gw(192, 168, 1, 1);
  IPAddress sn(255, 255, 255, 0);
  WiFi.config(ip, gw, sn, gw);
```

gw is gateway. the last parmeter is dns server's IP. sn is subnet mask.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but i checked my router configs and its is DHCP enabled

Comment: see DHCP logs in router if there is a record about DHCP request from the esp

Answer (score -1):

If your powering the device via a computer USB port there is a good chance it’s not providing enough power for the wifi.
Try powering fron an external source.

Comment: where did you get this? 500 mA from USB is enough. he has no motor connected